# Adding Google reCAPTCHA to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate Google reCAPTCHA in my Chrome Extension. 
I see the reCAPTCHA displayed in the Chrome Extension. 
But, it has the following written on it : "ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key" .

I understand that I should write the domain of my chrome extension in my captcha domains list. But how should I go about doing it ? Or am I thinking it the wrong way.

**EDIT**
I have a simple form as below:

```html
<form action="">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="****"></div>
        <button id="submitBtn" disabled>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

[The error captcha image is in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWvPS.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details/code of your chrome extension?

Comment: I have made some edits.

Comment: did you get any solution regarding this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need just add your domain on [google recaptcha admin console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TspV.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).